# MBP Retina screen, shows facebook page faded even after closed

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I'm experiencing something a bit odd on retina screen of my MBP 15".

When i stay on facebook homepage for like 10-15 seconds then close it. Then switch to a greyish application, i can definitely see; search box, friend list on right etc. faded on greyish application.

After a minute or so, it totally disappears... I tried to capture its screenshot but it wasnt same on screenshot. So obviously it is hardware-related, not something specifically designed into software.

Do you experience this too?
Should I contact Apple about this?

EDIT: I tried it with other "too white pages" but it didnt result same or it wasnt obvious enough.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is called ghosting and happens on MBPs with LG display units.

http://www.macworld.co.uk/mac/news/?newsid=3435647